How to pass tinytex options to `quarto::quarto_render()`
I'm using quarto::quarto_render() to render my Quarto documents, and I want to disable the automatic update of TeX Live Manager by setting options(tinytex.tlmgr_update = FALSE). However, it seems that this option is not being respected when I call quarto::quarto_render().
Here is what I have tried so far:
options(tinytex.tlmgr_update = FALSE)
quarto::quarto_render("my_document.qmd")

Additionally, does the RStudio Render button respect the options(tinytex.tlmgr_update = FALSE) setting?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Have you tried setting latex-auto-install to false? https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/pdf.html#latexmk

This seems to solve the issue. However, I would still like to know if this is the intended usage and why tinytex options are not utilized within the R console for quarto. If you write your comment as an answer, I will accept it.
